# Why doesn't this error message point to the first invalid octal number in the list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, octal

I understand that a weird error I had was coming from the fact that some input numbers were interpreted as octal. But how comes, in the following line, that for example a "9" does not generate an error, but a "8" does?

```
    MY_LIST = [152,187,267,362,935,040,097,262,292,333,135,334,337,144,288,317,3
43,172,032,160,289,186,916,039,274,069,018,911,081,286,356]
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Comment: Both are invalid, as well as `039` and a few others... I suspect that you have the output wrapped around - it actually points to `097`

Comment: Why do you think `069` is an acceptable octal number?

Comment: @Christian I am not the one thinking that :) It's the python processor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`069` is not a valid octal number, and neither are several others, including `018`.

Python is pointing you to `097` however, the first number starting with `0` that is *not* a valid octal number. Your console **wrapped** the error message and you interpreted the error message as pointing at the `018` value, but it is really the line *above* that that contains the error.

Compare the wrapped version:

```
    MY_LIST = [152,187,267,362,935,040,097,262,292,333,135,334,337,144,288,317,3
43,172,032,160,289,186,916,039,274,069,018,911,081,286,356]
                                         ^
```

with the un-wrapped version:

```
MY_LIST = [152,187,267,362,935,040,097,262,292,333,135,334,337,144,288,317,343,172,032,160,289,186,916,039,274,069,018,911,081,286,356]
                                     ^
```

It is your console that did the wrapping, *not Python*.

The preceding number `040` is valid octal and all numbers before that all start with a digit other than `0` and are not octal numbers.

Note that in my experience, the Windows console isn't directly resizable; you'd have to alter the console settings to increase the column count if you wanted to test against a larger or smaller window. See [Why is the Windows cmd.exe limited to 80 characters wide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319305/why-is-the-windows-cmd-exe-limited-to-80-characters-wide)

Your problem would be easier diagnosed with a list with some of the elements removed from the end.

Comment: Wow, that was weird, I even thought I had checked that... Is it ok if I delete the question?

Comment: @Antonio: since I stand to gain from upvotes on my post, I [put it before the Python chatroom community](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/21374539#21374539) to see what they think. I'm on the fence on this one.

Comment: My cmd is configured to be pretty wide, but for the first (and probably last) time in my life I had tried to use "run in interactive mode", which defaults to 80 column.