# Can the maximum line width in the terminal be increased in PyCharm?

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm

In PyCharm, the terminal appears to have a maximum width of 265 characters.

To see this, run the following at a python prompt in the PyCharm terminal:

```py
print('x' * 264)  # displays a long row of xxxxxxx on one line
print('x' * 265)  # wraps the newline character onto a new line
print('x' * 266)  # wraps one of the x's onto a new line
```

Is there a setting in PyCharm to increase this limit on line width?

I would like to print out lines that are longer than this, to compare with output from a different program.

I realise that I could write the output to a file from Python, but for quick debugging it is often convenient to print to the terminal.

Comment: This has been asked before. Are you sure answers such as in [How do I set the maximum line length in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319422/how-do-i-set-the-maximum-line-length-in-pycharm) do not work?

Comment: I have looked, both on stackoverflow and on google, and not found anyone else asking this question. The question you linked to is about setting the line width in the *editor*, rather than in the *terminal*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In PyCharm, the terminal appears to have a maximum width of 265 characters.

What PyCharm does is use a [terminal emulator](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/terminal-emulator.html#configure-the-terminal-emulator) to call one of the terminals/shells installed on your system. So the properties are native to whatever terminal you configure the IDE to use. The terminal can be chosen at `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Tools` `>` `Terminal` `>` `Application Settings` `>` `Shell path`, see the screenshot (in this example Windows `cmd.exe`).

[image]

Setting the column length is not PyCharm specific but something native to the terminal/shell/OS you are using. So setting this property will be different depending on your system, in the example using Windows `cmd.exe` it can be set using Microsoft [mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mode) as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/375505). The screenshot shows the running example from the question.

[image]