# Pyfiglet/Python - Print Pyfiglet ASCII in one line

Tags: python, fonts, pycharm, output, ascii

This is my code to print "x t e k k y" whit a cool ASCII font using pyfiglet, but the output always displays in 2 lines, whith gives a bad aestethic, is there any way to fix that?

```
from pyfiglet import figlet_format
from termcolor import colored

art = figlet_format("x t e k k y", font='alligator')
c_art = colored(art, 'blue')

print(c_art)
```

output:
[image]

Comment: My first guess is that either `pyfiglet` or `termcolor` have some terminal length as default. Does it still split to two lines if you skip the `colored` function and just do `print(art)`?

Comment: @SNygard related [Can the maximum line width in the terminal be increased in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67645105)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the width property in the format like so

```
art = figlet_format("x t e k k y", font='alligator', width=110)
```

Adjust the width until it prints all on one line. The wider the width the wider the 'page' you are printing on.
Happy coding!